# Unit testing an angular directive wrapping slickgrid

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, angularjs, angularjs-directive, slickgrid

I would like to test my angular directive that is a wrapper around slickgrid.

```
'use strict';
describe('Unit: Grid Directive', function() {
  var $scope;
  var element;

  beforeEach(module('grid'));
  beforeEach(inject(function($compile, $rootScope) {
    $scope = $rootScope;    
    element = angular.element('<grid class="slickgrid-table" id="miscGrid" query="query"/>');
    $scope.query = { symbol: 'AAAA' };
    $compile(element)($scope);
    $scope.$digest();
  }));
```

The problem is that slickgrid uses jquery to find the id for where it should insert it's grid.

```
Error: SlickGrid requires a valid container, #miscGrid does not exist in the DOM.
```

My question is, how can I get this to work? How can I "trick" slickgrid in to realizing that the element I'm trying to compile is a valid container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than tricking anything I've found it easier to just append the element to the DOM for most cases.
According to an example from project's githithub, the control needs to be in the DOM to be initialised properly anyway (http://mleibman.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example-explicit-initialization.html)

I tend to put the following lines in any directive specs

```
var sandbox;
beforeEach(function() { sandbox = angular.element('<div>'); angular.element(document.body).append(sandbox); });
afterEach(function() { sandbox.remove(); sandbox = null; });
```

Then just append your directive to sandbox before you compile it.